# can mining be done from different computers using same eth account

Tags: mining, cpu

i am trying to setup ethereum mining cluster and i have 3 desktops for this running ubuntu 16.04 with 6 CPU each and 0 GPU.

Is it possible to configure these 3 servers in cluster and using the same etherium account can i increase the overall hash processed/second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just specify the same address on all the miners.  The blockchain will handle the allocation of ether to that address.

You don't need to run them in a cluster to accomplish mining into the same account.